# Javascript dynamic event in for

Tags: javascript, list, for-loop

I have a little JavaScript code, that loop throw in a list, and create a slider for each element. In second, it's take an event handler, so when a slider is changed, it'll write the value in to an input.

When the for run for the first time, everything is ok, the inputs gets the values, but when i change manualy the slider, it throw an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'maxValue' of undefined

The code:

```
for (i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++)
{
    noUiSlider.create(sliders[i].object[0], {
        start: sliders[i].start,
        step: 1,
        connect: true,
        range: sliders[i].range
    });
    sliders[i].object[0].noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
        if ( handle ) {
            console.debug(sliders[i]);
            sliders[i].maxValue.val(Math.floor(values[handle]));
        } else {
            sliders[i].minValue.val(Math.floor(values[handle]));
        }
    });
}
```

In the sliders variable i have this:

```
var sliders = [
            {
                "object": $('#number-of-passangers'),
                "start": [4, 6],
                "range": {
                    "min": 2,
                    "max": 15
                },
                "minValue": $("#min-passanger"),
                "maxValue": $("#max-passanger")
            },
            {
                "object": $('#cost-per-day'),
                "start": [3500, 65000],
                "range": {
                    "min": 3500,
                    "max": 65000
                },
                "minValue": $("#min-cost"),
                "maxValue": $("#max-cost")
            },
        ]
```

Comment: What does sliders contains, how we can get length using sliders.length ? nowhere it's defined in code. can you post the full code ?

Comment: sliders is a simple variable:

`var sliders = [
    {
     "object": $('#number-of-passangers'),
     "start": [4, 6],
     "range": {
      "min": 2,
      "max": 15
     },
     "minValue": $("#min-passanger"),
     "maxValue": $("#max-passanger")
    },
    {
     "object": $('#cost-per-day'),
     "start": [3500, 65000],
     "range": {
      "min": 3500,
      "max": 65000
     },
     "minValue": $("#min-cost"),
     "maxValue": $("#max-cost")
    },
   ]`

Comment: Update the question and provide full source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `i` is the index of the loop, which is incremented AFTER each iteration. Before the increment `i < sliders.length` is evaluated and if true, the loop body is executed. That means, after the loop has finished `i == sliders.length`, so `sliders[i]`is undefined. `i` resides in the outer scope of the event handler, so its value will be the same for each event handler. You need to save a local copy of it like:

```
.on('click', (function (idx) {
    return function (values, handle) {
        /* use idx here, instead of i*/ 
    }
 })(i));
```

To sum up, your Problem is caused by the scope. If you consider:

```
function make () {
    for (var i = 0, result = []; i < 10; i++) {
        result.push(function fxi () { console.log(i); });
    }
    return result;
}

make().forEach(function (fxi) { fxi () }) // logs 10 time »10«
```

That is because `i` is defined in the scope of `make()` and if one of the inner functions `fxi` is invoked, the definition of `i` is searched, which is not found within the scope of `fxi`, so the search goes on at the next level, `make()` this time, there is is found, so its value taken from there. But since the loop has incremented `i` up to 10 while running, its value is now 10 for each `fxi`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7hzo1d5/1/)